# Python: How to separate array into chunks

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, nested-loops

I am still very new to python programming

I have an array I am trying to break down into chuncks.
My array seems to have multiple arrays within it (I think).

The output looks something like this:

```
[array([None, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
       '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', None, None, None],
      dtype=object)
 array([None, None, '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', None, None,
       None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
       None], dtype=object)
 array([None, None, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', None, None, None, None,
       None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
       None], dtype=object)
```

This a snippet of the printed output. Is there any way to display this output in one array with 24 columns?

I created my array based off a dataframe I created with 24 columns. I wanted to populate those columns using a for loop. The loop works but it only populates the array.

Here is some sample output from my dataframe. I have **24 "status"** columns and a column named **"Account Opened Date"**

this is the output of one of the status columns:

```
0       1
1       0
2       P
3       0
4    None
Name: status6, dtype: object
```

The idea is to take the output of all 24 status columns and place them in new columns named **"stat"** which will also have a range of 24. so the output of **status 24** would be populated in **stat 1** and **status 23** would populate **stat 2** etc.

I saw this example of how to break an array into chunks but I couldn't get the output I wanted.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/break-list-chunks-size-n-python/

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

#add stat1-24 into the data frame
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame({
        'stat1':'','stat2':'','stat3':'','stat4':'',
        'stat5':'','stat6':'','stat7':'','stat8':'',
        'stat9':'','stat10':'','stat11':'','stat12':'',
        'stat13':'','stat14':'','stat15':'','stat16':'',
        'stat17':'','stat18':'','stat19':'','stat20':'',
        'stat21':'','stat22':'','stat23':'','stat24':'',},index=df.index))

#call status1-24 from the data frame and store the columns in an array
status = df.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[6:30])

#call stat1-24 from the data frame and store the columns in an array
stat = df.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[31:55])

l = len(df)

#calculate difference in months between startDate and AccountOpenedDate
def monthly_diff(d2,startDate):
    return(d2.year - startDate.year) * 12 + d2.month - startDate.month

startDate = date(year=2017, month = 7, day = 1)

df['Difference_IN_Months'] = df['AccountOpenedDate']


for x in range(l):
    d2_1=df['AccountOpenedDate'][x]
    d2=d2_1.date()
    df['Difference_IN_Months'][x]= monthly_diff(d2,startDate)
    for i in range(0,23):
        if 3 <= 24 - monthly_diff(d2,startDate) - i + 1 <=24:    
            stat[x,i] = status[24 - monthly_diff(d2,startDate) - i + 1] 
        else: stat[x,i]=''


print(stat[1,:])
```

I hope my code isn't too confusing. Everything works fine except the part where my array "stat" should populate my dataframe columns (stat1-stat24) with the relevant data.

Comment: What do you mean by " Is there any way to display this output in one array with 24 columns?"

Comment: Please provide the output of the dataframe..  What it looks like...Because looking at this i have no idea what your code is doing.

Comment: Hi Andy_101. I wanted to take the output of my for loop and store it in my data frame. My data frame output looks like this(above):  I have 24 "status" columns in my data frame. I wanted to take the data in all 24 columns and place it in 24 new "stat" columns in reverse order using my nested for loop. This works fine however, the data got stored in my array named "stat". I wanted the output to populate straight into my data frame but I found a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can understand from your code and question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



start=0
l=[np.array([None, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
       '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', None, None, None],
      dtype=object),
 np.array([None, None, '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', None, None,
       None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
       None], dtype=object),
 np.array([None, None, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', None, None, None, None,
       None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
       None], dtype=object)]

d={'stat1':'','stat2':'','stat3':'','stat4':'','stat5':'','stat6':'','stat7':'','stat8':'','stat9':'','stat10':'','stat11':'','stat12':'','stat13':'','stat14':'','stat15':'','stat16':'','stat17':'','stat18':'','stat19':'','stat20':'','stat21':'','stat22':'','stat23':'','stat24':''}     
df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=[0])

print(df)
for i in l:
    df.loc[len(df)] = i
print(df)
```

output:

```
  stat1 stat2 stat3 stat4 stat5 stat6 stat7 stat8 stat9  ... stat16 stat17 stat18 stat19 stat20 stat21 stat22 stat23 stat24
0                                                        ...

[1 rows x 24 columns]


  stat1 stat2 stat3 stat4 stat5 stat6 stat7 stat8 stat9  ... stat16 stat17 stat18 stat19 stat20 stat21 stat22 stat23 stat24
0                                                        ...
1  None     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0   None   None   None
2  None  None     0     0     0     1     0     0     0  ...   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None
3  None  None     0     0     0     0     0     0  None  ...   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None

[4 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: This is the output I wanted to achieve

Comment: good. so problem solved :-)   use :       df.loc[len(df)] = i

Answer (score 0):

As I understood in your example data you have "array rows" in an array and you would like to convert those "nested rows" to columns. If that is the case you can do the following (I assume the original array is stored in `array_to_split`):

```
# Create a 24xnumber_of_nested_arrays size array
array_split_to_columns = np.zeros((len(array_to_split[0]), len(array_to_split)))

# Then fill it with the data of the nested array
for column in range(0, len(array_to_split)):
    array_split_to_columns[:,column] = array_to_split[column]
```

In this case the `array_split_to_columns` variable looks like:

```
[[nan nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. nan]
 [ 0.  0. nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [ 0. nan nan]
 [nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan]]
```

I hope it will help you fill your Pandas Dataframe. If you have any questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: Hi ajlaj25. Thank you for this. I found a workaround for my problem. Should I post it?

Comment: I am happy that you found a solution! If it did not help you then no, thank you :)